# Double Clicking event on Android's Screen

Tags: android, toast, double-click

I am new to Android. Actually whenever I make double click on android screen(layout), I want to create a `Toast`.But whenever I make a double click on screen nothing happens. Please solve my problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDoubleTapListener,OnGestureListener{

   int clickCount = 0;
   long startTime;
   long duration;
   static final int MAX_DURATION = 500;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(this,this);
    detector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            if(e.getAction()==1)
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onSingleTapConfirmed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            if(e.getAction()==1)
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDoubleTapEvent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            if(e.getAction()==1)
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDoubleTap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

If you want to attach the Dector on a particular View

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayoutId);
layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {      
                return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
});
```

Comment: ok..but if i have a linear layout,so is it working if i click at any place?bcoz after clicking i want to have a pop up window?

Comment: @Aditya do you want the doubletap event only on your LinearLayout?

Comment: @blackbelt yes sir..i have only a simple linear layout.I only want on layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayoutId);
   layout .setOnTouchListener(this);
   gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
```

and use this class like inner class

```
 public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener implements OnGestureListener   {

           @Override
           public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDoubleTapEvent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return super.onDoubleTap(e);

                }
            }


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){
        Log.v(TAG,"screen touched");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: means i have to write another class in my already existing class?

Comment: better you can use like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like Double Tap then you have to use  [GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html)

Comment: @SankarV Yes i have used it already.I want to click on anywhere in linear layout